# What is the grammar for the following sentence: "It is used to avoid legal action should future problems arise"?

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what the associated grammar with this sentence is:

> "Disclaimers are a simple device used by sellers to avoid legal action should future problems arise".

Actually, I don't know why an inverse structure is used here.

Comment: I'd toss in a comma after *action*.

Comment: Why? I think that it would be wrong to do such thing. I upgraded my sentence to its more complete form.

Answer (score 0):

"It is used to avoid legal action should future problems arise".
I agree that there should be a comma after 'action'. The sentence might make more sense if you knew what the pronoun 'it' is referring back to. The sentence is trying to qualify and give an explanation for whatever has gone before and explain the reasons for such use (to avoid potential future problems).